# If $π_0$ is the orthogonal projection onto the space $H_0$ of constant $L^2(\mu)$-functions, then $π_0f=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $H_\lambda$ be a closed subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ for $\lambda\ge0$ such that $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ is nondecreasing. Assume $H_0$ is the space of constant functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Let $\pi_\lambda$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H_\lambda$ onto $H_0$.

> Are we able to conclude $$\pi_0f=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\tag1$$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$?

By assumption, we should obtain $$\langle\pi_\lambda1,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=\langle1,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=\int g\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda\ge0\text{ and }g\in L^2(\mu)\tag2.$$ Now $(1)$ seems to be trivial, but how do we need to argue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, (1) is not true.

The projection is characterized by
$\pi_0 f \in H_0$, i.e., $\pi_0 f$ is a constant function (with value $c_f$), and
$$(\pi_0 f, g) = (f, g) \qquad \forall g \in H_0.$$

Plug in $g = 1$ to obtain
$$ \int_\Omega c_f \, \mathrm d\mu = \int_\Omega f \, \mathrm{d}\mu.$$
Thus,
$$
c_f = \frac{\int_\Omega f \, \mathrm d\mu}{\mu(\Omega)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In a Hilbert space the projection $P$ on the space spanned by  single unit vector $x$ is given  by $Py= \langle y, x \rangle x$. Take $x$ to be the constant function $1/\sqrt {\mu (\Omega)}$.

Comment: This is not entirely true, the constant function does not have norm $1$.

Comment: @gerw Thanks. I was assuming that $\mu$ was  probability measure.